# How can we compile and debug the code in run time written in Java?

Tags: java

I don't know if its possible though I looked for some solutions but again not sure if it going to work.

What I've found is:
https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Runtime-Compiler
and:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOR

what I tried to accomplish is writing Java code and my app to compile it ( to memory or not )  but important feature is that I need to be able to debug the runtime code in  IDE or remote.

Where to start from?

Comment: You are using which editor?

Comment: using eclipse or Intellij

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of an IDE that doesn't come with a built-in debugger. I myself am using IntelliJ. Just run the code in "debug mode", add breakpoints at the lines you want to debug, and in runtime, the application will halt and wait for your next commands.

Comment: this is less of problem i guess any thing loads into the JVM will be debuggable
But main question is how to compile in runtime

Answer (score 1):

For remote debugging, your server debug port should be opened (server should be in debug mode). Through the IDE (eclipse, IntelliJ), you have to set the debug port.
Once you pointer reached to the debug point, you can compile your code.

Comment: This is great and i know but my main problem how to load and compile code in runtime